# golang multithreaded web crawler runs into deadlock

Tags: multithreading, go, channel

I just started to learn multithreaded programming using golang, and I'm trying to write a multithreaded web crawler using BFS traversal, however I cannot get the code working. The error I get is `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

I will paste the code below, but let me explain conceptually how it works:

I have one master thread (the main function itself) and N worker threads. I intentionally chose to use BFS approach with a fixed amount of worker threads, because it seems using a DFS approach I will have to spawn a new thread for each single new URL to crawl, which might become a huge burden for context switch.

I am using two channels:

1. urlsToCrawl: master thread sends URLs to crawl to worker threads.
2. urlsDiscovered: worker threads send discovered URLs back to master.

Here is the code implementation, I removed some non relevant details (e.g. how to parse html page etc..)

The trick I'm trying to do here is: I am using the channel as a queue to do BFS, and when the queue's size is 0, it is impossible to know whether it is because "A. there is really no more URLs to crawl" OR because "B. some worker thread(s) are still working so there might be more URLs to crawl soon". Therefore I introduced this `count` variable, basically whenever a new url is sent to workers to be crawled, `count` is incremented, therefore when `count == 0` and channel is empty, it would mean "A. there is really no more URLs to crawl"; otherwise when `count > 0` and channel is empty, it would mean "B. some worker thread(s) are still working so there might be more URLs to crawl soon".

However as I mentioned, this doesn't seem to work and I run into deadlock. Would anyone please shed some light? Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    count = 0   // This tracks how many worker threads are actively working right now
)

func crawlUrl(urlsToCrawl chan string, urlsDiscovered chan Pair) {
    for url := range urlsToCrawl {
        urls := getUrls(url)  // This returns an array of string, if no URL found, it returns an empty array
        urlsDiscovered <- urls
    }
}

func main() {
    urlsToCrawl := make(chan string)
    urlsDiscovered := make(chan string[])
    i := 0
    for i < 8 {
        go crawlUrl(urlsToCrawl, urlsDiscovered)
        i++
    }
    visited := map[string]bool{"some_seed_url": true}
    count++
    urlsToCrawl <- "some_seed_url"
    for urls := range urlsDiscovered {
        count--  // One message is received by master, meaning one worker thread has finished an job item, therefore decrementing count
        for _, url := range urls {
            _, ok := visited[url]
            if ok {
                continue  // This URL has been crawled before
            }
            visited[url] = true
            count ++  // One more work item will be sent to worker, therefore first increment count
            urlsToCrawl <- url
        }
        if count == 0 {
            close(urlsDiscovered)
            close(urlsToCrawl)
            break
        }  // else some worker must be working so let's wait to see if there is new msg coming through the channel
    }
}
```

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bgo%5d%20crawl

Answer (score 0):

Your channels are unbuffered

```
urlsToCrawl := make(chan string)
urlsDiscovered := make(chan string[])
```

So a goroutine which reads from or writes to a channel will block until a goroutine on the other side is doing the opposite.

So you start 8 `crawlUrl` goroutines which all block while reading from `urlsToCrawl`, meaning that `main` can send 8 urls before blocking. The `crawlUrl` goroutines are blocked until `main` reads from `urlsDiscovered`. So if you have more than 8 URL's going around, all goroutines are waiting on each other(deadlock).

The solution to this is to use [buffered channels](https://gobyexample.com/channel-buffering) with a capacity you are very unlikely to exceed:

```golang
urlsToCrawl := make(chan string, 1000)
urlsDiscovered := make(chan string[], 100)
```

If you expect you might still exceed the capacity of the channel in extreme cases, you can perform [non-blocking operations](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations) which allow you to for example discard discovered URL's if the channel is full instead of blocking.

```golang
select {
case: urlsDiscovered <- urls:
  // on success (url written)
default:
  // channel is full, can't write without blocking
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So basically `main` is blocked waiting for some worker thread to receive the msg, whereas all worker threads are blocked waiting for `main` thread to receive the crawl result <-- deadlock.


I would've never thought that's the cause of it. I switched to use buffered channel as you suggested, and now it works all well for my small demo dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try to integrate the **WaitGroup** package.